# Thread safe array for std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
mystruct** = (mystruct**)calloc(10, sizeof(mystruct*);
for(unsignd int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    mystruct[i] = (mystruct*)calloc(10, sizeof(mystruct);

thread t[10];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    t[i] = thread(new_piece, mystruct[i]);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    t[i].join();
```

The function `new_piece` writes data to `mystruct[i]`. To be more specific, the function changes the values of `mystruct[i][0], mystruct[i][1], ..., mystruct[9]`

How to make the above operation thread safe?

Comment: If `thread[i]` touches only `mystruct[i]`, then you have nothing to worry about. You don't share the data between threads : other threads don't know anything about `mystruct[i-1]` or `mystruct[i+1]`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar You might worry about _cache trashing_.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper : You're right, I did not take this into account. Thanks!

Comment: So, in the case of cache trashing my code is unsafe?

Comment: usually people write a new allocator, maybe a pool allocator, instead of doing this dance, your code is error prone, hard to read and not really C++-ish. Try to write a new allocator first.

Comment: It's not unsafe, but the performance might suffer. The solution would be to ensure that a _mystruct_ would be aligned to _cache-lines_, and thus no instance of a _mystruct_ would share a cache-line with any other _mystruct_.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper is it possible that you write code targeting the problems've mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, the code seems to be "thread-safe", however it might suffer from "cache-thrashing".

First let me explain what it is, and why this might happen in your code:

#### What is cache-thrashing:

A "cache-line" is the smallest unit of data which gets fetched into the cache from memory. Note that the size of the cache-line is a hardware property. There's no language construct which would yield this value. Most cache-line sizes on modern CPUs are 64 bytes.

Cache-thrashing occurs on systems with multiple CPUs and a coherent cache when different threads access distinct variables which happen to be layout in memory which share the same cache line. This will lead to excessive cache misses, and thus results in degraded performance.

(See also wiki article [false-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)) which refers to the *usage pattern* which causes cache-thrashing)

(See also: Dr.Dobb's article [Eliminate False Sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206))

#### Why might it happen in your code:

Allocation blocks returned from `calloc` or `malloc` strive to be as small as possible and are packed tightly together. That is, different allocation blocks may share the same cache-line (see also `man 3 calloc`, e.g. [FreeBSD man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=calloc&sektion=3&format=html)).

C++'s `new` operator won't be different.

Now, that we cannot generally assume that memory blocks returned from `calloc` or `malloc` will not share a common cache-line, your code may suffer from cache-thrashing, since your instances of *mystruct* which are accessed simultaneously from different threads may share a common cache-line.

#### How to avoid "cache-thrashing":

Basically, you ensure this through properly aligning your data (see wiki article [Data Structure Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)).

There are many approaches where you can ensure your data (*mystruct*) is properly cache-aligned, for example:

- Use `malloc` or `calloc` and round your allocation requests up to the nearest multiple of the cache-line size.
- utilise a posix function: `posix_memalign`, declared in header `<stdlib.h>` (see opengroup [posix_memalign](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/posix_memalign.html))
- In C++11, you can use `std::aligned_storage` (see definition [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage))

  `std::aligned_storage` provides for a `type` which is suitable for use as *uninitialized* storage where you can store your object.

  For example, defining a cache-line aligned storage which is an array for N instances:

  ```
  struct mystruct { ... };

  const std::size_t cache_line_size = 64;

  typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(mystruct), cache_line_size>::type storage[N];
  ```

  With that, you now could define a class which wraps an array of N cache-line aligned `mystruct`s, which also provides convenient accessor functions to modify and retrieve a `mystruct` value at position *i* in the underlying array. IMO, this approach would be much preferred over your error prone approach using a loop and calloc for instantiating the storage for your `mystruct` array.

  See the example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), which - slightly modified - would perfectly fit your needs.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. What kind of performance degree can I expect (5% or 50% for example) and will this even happen if I have many GBs of memory unused?

Comment: @Luka Don't make guesses, *measure*!  ;) That is, implement two variations: one uses a cache-aligned storage (use a reasonable small my_struct, say just an char as field), and the other doesn't use cache-aligend storage. Then *measure*. Of course, the higher the frequency of simultaneous accesses, the higher the expected differences in performance.